Add Horizontal Text using Tikz
I am trying to make a template for my AP Classroom that is similar to the picture that is shown.  I am wondering how to add the text ''Do not write beyond this border.  I am having trouble because when I try to draw the node for it, my page border misaligns.  Here is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
\draw
($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)$)
--($(current page.north west)+(1.5cm,-1.5cm)$)
--($(current page.south west)+(1.5cm,1.5cm)$)
--($(current page.south east)+(-1.5cm,1.5cm)$)
--cycle;

\end{document}


This works until I add my practice questions.  The picture gets pushed down.  I have tried moving both the text and pictue, but it is not working
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\begin{document}     

\rule{.8\textwidth}{2pt}
\section*{AP Calculus BC}
\subsection*{Free-Response Question}

\newpage

   
\begin{enumerate}
    
    \item The Maclaurin series for \(\ln\big(1+x\big)\) is given by 
    \[ x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+\big(-1\big)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}+\cdots.\]

On its interval of convergence, this series converges to \(\ln\left(1+x\right)\).  Let \(f\) be the function defined by \(f\left(x\right)=x\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x}{3}\right)\). 

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Write the first four nonzero terms and the general term of the Maclaurin series for \(f\). 

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw ([shift={(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)}]current page.north east) rectangle ([shift={(1.5cm,1.5cm)}]current page.south west);
  \node[rotate=270] at ([xshift=-0.75cm]current page.east) {Do not write beyond this border.};
  \node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=0.75cm]current page.west) {Do not write beyond this border.};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}

'''


You could use the rotate=... option to rotate the text of a node:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw ([shift={(-1.5cm,-1.5cm)}]current page.north east) rectangle ([shift={(1.5cm,1.5cm)}]current page.south west);
  \node[rotate=270] at ([xshift=-0.75cm]current page.east) {Do not write beyond this border.};
  \node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=0.75cm]current page.west) {Do not write beyond this border.};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\duckument% dummy text

\end{document}





This works but when I add text, the picture gets pushed down.  The text will not fit in the box.

@NickB Please make a small but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce your problem.

I updated with the code I was having issues with from my original post

@NickB ... but the code in your question does not include a picture. I'm confused what get pushed down?

I was able to fix it. I was referring to the entire Tikz picture (Rectangle)

To avoid moving the frame rectangle, we can separate in to 2 tikzpictures with [remember picture,overlay] (so compile twice) in the first tikzpicture, as the code in here. The top text needs more care.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy texts only
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!20}
\setcounter{page}{6}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path 
(current page.south west)+(2,2.5)   coordinate (A)
(current page.south east)+(-2,2.5)  coordinate (B) 
(current page.north east)+(-2,-2) coordinate (C) 
(current page.north west)+(2,-2)  coordinate (D) 
(A)--(D) coordinate[midway] (M)
(B)--(C) coordinate[midway] (N)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[thick] (A) rectangle (C);
\path 
(N)+(.5,0) node[rotate=270]{Do not write on this border.}
(M)+(-.5,0) node[rotate=90] {Do not write on this border.}
(A)+(4,-.75) node[draw,align=left]{Unauthorized copying or reuse of\\any part of this page is illegal.}
(B)+(-3,-.75) node{Problem 2 is continued on page 7.}
;
\foreach \i[count=\k] in {.1,.2,...,.9}{ 
\pgfmathparse{mod(\k,2) ? "gray!20" : "yellow!20"}
\path (D)--(C) node[pos=\i,yshift=9mm,scale=3,fill=\pgfmathresult]{\bfseries 2};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


Looks great, except that I need to add that code to each new page.  Is there a way that I could make that format for all pages, so I don't have to keep placing them to sets of code either before or after new text?
